# Magento; dispatch multi store

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I've set up the following multi site structure in Magento (1.3.2.4);

```
Site   | Store   | View
--------------------------
Site A | Store A | View A
Site B | Store B | -
```

So, 2 site codes and 1 view code.

- Is the (empty) view of Store B inherited from Store A?
- And what if "Store B" was left blank, would that inherit the root category of "Store A"?

**My major question**

I want to dispatch a certain store/site by code, respectively my site codes are 'site_a' and 'site_b'.

I have a filesystem that looks like this (goal is not to customize the magento directory).

./sites/site_a/.htaccess

./sites/site_a/magento/

'setEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE site_a' is added to my htaccess in the root of site_a (found this on internet, im not sure of this is implemented by magento..)

I expected switching the RUN_CODE to 'site_b' would load 'Site B' at /site_a/magento/, but it doesn't.

Any help is appreciated :-)

// Roland

Edit:
Offcourse $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] exists (with the correct value and matching the configured value) in /site_a/magento/.

Im getting this feeling its not implemented :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of Magento, it may not be implemented by default and you will need to add some extra code to the bottom of Magento's index.php:

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

If using the codes from the websites (not the store views) then you will need to set MAGE_RUN_TYPE to 'website'.

I believe you will also need to set a store view for website B as it will not be inherited from website A.

Comment: I did some tests myself..

Nothing gets inherited. All stores *need* a site, store, view (dont leave them empty!).

Your right about the implementation of environment variables. I believe its implmenented as default in v.1.4